# Ember 1.0.0 input type radio 'checked' binding not updated when property changes

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've got a problem: I've got this property called 'active' on one of my models, it is either the string 'yes' or 'no', now I want to use this property to check a HTML radio button.

So when 'active' is 'yes' it should be checked otherwise it should not be checked. I've got this to work, however when I make an action that sets the 'active' property to 'no' or 'yes' the radio buttons checked status doesn't update.

Here's a bin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ohaSezo/3/edit.

When using a checkbox I get the same results: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OWILUru/3/edit

I can't make sense of it, I think this should work, any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`{{bind-attr}}` doesn't work that way - it only binds one way. Here are some examples of how you'd go about this:

Use `{{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding="car.active"}}`: [jsBin example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OWILUru/5/)

Or use a custom implementation of `Ember.RadioButton` - `{{view Ember.RadioButton checkedBinding="car.active"}}`: [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/chopper/CM6fK/35/)

Credit for `Ember.RadioButton`: [Thoughts & Ramblings of a Software Developer](http://thoughts.z-dev.org/2013/07/04/post/).

EDIT: Updated link as per Steve H.'s comment - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to chopper's answer, I fix the first jsBin example : http://jsbin.com/ziyililetogi/2/edit.
You can use `{{view Ember.RadioButton selectionBinding="car.active" value="true" name="car"}}`.